# Why can't mock.call() accept self as a kwarg?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, keyword-argument

## Background

In python mocking, there is a [function `assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) which can verify the order of arguments used to call a function. It has a [helper object `call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) which helps validate the arguments.

## Problem

Using `call()`, you cannot pass `self` as a kwarg. It gives the error: `TypeError: __call__() got multiple values for argument 'self'`. Why? The workaround is to simply not use self as a kwarg, but I'm afraid there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding and can't find anything in the documentation that points to it.

## Live Code

The code below is pasted here for you to play with: https://repl.it/@artoonie/ObviousIntentReality#main.py

## Pasted Code

#### File 1: `test_class.py`

*needs to be a separate file for mock.patch decorator discoverability*

```py
class Class:
  def func(self, num):
    return num

class Runner:
  def run(self):
    return Class().func(1)
```

#### File 2: `test.py`

```py
import mock
import test_class

unmockedFunction = test_class.Class.func

class Test:
  @mock.patch('test_class.Class.func', autospec=True)
  def test_me(self, mocker):
    # Make the mock do nothing
    mocker.side_effect = unmockedFunction

    # Run the function
    test_class.Runner().run()

    # This works
    mocker.assert_called_with(self=mock.ANY, num=1)

    # This works
    mocker.assert_has_calls([
      mock.call(mock.ANY, num=1)
    ])

    # This fails
    mocker.assert_has_calls([
      mock.call(self=mock.ANY, num=1)
    ])

Test().test_me()
```